# Android app structure for tablet and phones

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, android-layout

Today I updated an android application **.Apk to .aab** (Android App Bundle).
When uploading the .aab application in google play console everything works fine but it advises me:
Design your application for tablets.

With .apk does not tell me any advice because everything is correct. But with .aab he tells me this advice to optimize.

My question is:

**1- Would the following application structure be correct?**

Structure of my application:

- drawable
- layout
- layout-sw600dp
- layout-sw720dp
- mipmap-anydpi-v26
- mipmap-hdpi
- mipmap-mdpi
- mipmap-xhdpi
- mipmap-xxhdpi
- mipmap-xxxhdpi
- values
- values-sw600dp
- values-sw720dp

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @joan - you described one problem and asked a seemingly unrelated question. Consider revising your question to include why you think that the directory structure is a possible cause or the the problem you described

Comment: That message usually just means that you didn't upload any tablet sized screenshots.

Comment: On the tab, the play store> screenshot 7 and 10  a light bulb is displayed and says:
You have uploaded screenshots for 10-inch tablets, but it seems that the APK is not designed for this type of tablet.